# Is it possible to let PyCharm auto break line when writing long docstrings and comments?

Tags: python, editor, pycharm

Writing long docstrings and long comments is annoying because of the 80-characters width limit.

For example, I write something like:

```
def fun(self):
    """Return some thing

    This function do some complex work and return something that need a
    long sentence to describe
    """
```

And then I found I need to insert something in the third line of docstring. After inserting, the width is much longer than 80 characters, so I manually break it. However, after breaking, the length of forth line is much less than 80, and I have to merge the forth and fifth line, and break it at some proper place so that every line is not too short and too long. If there are more lines, this job gets more annoying.

Similar problem occurs when I found I have to delete something in the third line. Is there any trick, or plugin of PyCharm that deals with this problem? Since I'm using vim plugin in PyCharm, tricks for vim are also great.

Comment: `Edit -> Fill Paragraph`

Comment: @PeterWood Thank you, but this do not so good. It will merge the ALL the lines of docstring, even I only selected a part of them.

Comment: It doesn't merge all lines. It will merge a paragraph, i.e. text regions without a blank line between. If you want it to leave text alone you need a blank line between it and the text where the focus is.

Answer (score 6):

> `Edit -> Fill Paragraph`

Merges a paragraph, i.e. a text region without a blank line between.

If you want it to leave text alone you need a blank line between it and the text where the focus is